# Make list item elements stretch to width of widest element in list

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a group of containers in an unordered list. Each container has text content. I want the width of each container to be equal to the width of the widest list item container (as determined by text content). You can find the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-waterfall-iu28dt?file=/src/styles.css:95-330).

Here is the relevant lines of code:

```
<div className="App">
  <h1>Lender Benefits</h1>
  <ul className="list">
    {lenderBenefits.map((benefit) => (
      <li className="benefit_container">{benefit}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
.benefit_container {
  height: 28px;
  width: max-content;
  border-radius: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: #f1e8dc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

What do I have to do to the width to make all these containers have the same width as the third (and widest) in the list?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul {
  width: max-content;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  padding: 2px 8px;
  background-color: #f1e8dc;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third and longest line</li>
</ul>
```